# LDA classification: Is zero predictive power in test data set real, or artefact of error

Tags: r, classification, lda

I have a tab delimited file with 70 rows of data and 34 columns of characteristics, where the first 60 rows look like this:

```
groups x1    x2     x3    x4   x5 (etc, up to x34)
0    0.1    0.5    0.5   0.4  0.2
1    0.2    0.3    0.8   0.4  0.1
0    0.4    0.7    0.6   0.2  0.1
1    0.4    0.4    0.7   0.1  0.4
```

And the last 10 rows look like this:

```
groups x1    x2     x3    x4   x5
?    0.2    0.1    0.5   0.4  0.2
?    0.2    0.1    0.8   0.4  0.1
?    0.2    0.2    0.6   0.2  0.1
?    0.2    0.3    0.7   0.1  0.4
```

The groups are binary (i.e. each row either belongs to group 0 or group 1). The aim is to use the first 60 rows as my training data set, and the last 10 rows as my test data set; to classify the last 10 rows into groups 0 or 1.

I wrote this, following the method described [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/84669_cd15214061d44e1493ffee69c5d55925.html):

```
data <-read.table("data_challenge_test.tab",header=TRUE)
train <-sample(1:60)
data.train <-data[train,]
data.test <-data[-train,]
odd.lda <-lda(groups ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5, data.train)
pred.train <- predict(odd.lda,data.train)$class
pred.test <- predict(odd.lda,data.test)$class

training_prediction = mean(pred.train == data.train$groups)
testing_prediction = mean(pred.test == data.test$groups)
```

After the "odd.lda" line, I get the warning:

```
Warning message:
In lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : group ? is empty
```

The problem is that my test training data set should not have group "?" in it at all (since my training data set is the first 60 rows that are all grouped either 0 or 1).

Then, my training_prediction value is 0.9, but my test_prediction value is 0.

I understand that I could also consider other methods of classification (I am also looking into glm), but I want to make sure that the 0 predictive power obtained from the test_prediction data set is real, and not an artefact of a mistake (i.e. the issue with the group numbers that I have above).

Have I done this analysis properly, or is there a mistake in the above code that has led to the warning described above, and the 0 predictive power of the test data set.

Edit 1:
Due to discussion in the comments, in order to calculate the predictive power of the model, I copied the approach described [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/35817_2552e05f1d4e4db8ba87b334101a43da.html), which randomly selects 50 of 60 rows, estimates the training parameters, and then classifies the remaining 10 samples. This is repeated 100 times.

```
n = 60
nt = 50
neval = n-nt
rep=100
errlin = dim(rep)

set.seed(123456789)
data <-read.table("data_challenge_test.tab",header=TRUE)
data <-data[1:60,]
for (k in 1:rep) {
train = sample(1:n,nt)
data.train <-data[train,]
data.test <-data[-train,]
m1 = lda(groups ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5,data.train)
tablin = table(data$groups[-train],predict(m1,data.test)$class)
errlin[k] = (neval-sum(diag(tablin)))/neval
}
merrlin=mean(errlin)
merrlin
```

In my case, merrlin is 0.454; meaning that there is a 45% mis-classification.

Exact code used on Iris data set (see comments below):

```
n = 120
nt = 90
neval = n-nt
rep=100
errlin = dim(rep)
set.seed(123456789)
data <-iris
for (k in 1:rep) {
  train = sample(1:n,nt)
  data.train <-data[train,]
  data.test <-data[-train,]
  m1 = lda(Species ~ .,data.train)
  tablin = table(data$Species[-train],predict(m1,data.test)$class)
  errlin[k] = (neval-sum(diag(tablin)))/neval
}

merrlin=mean(errlin)
merrlin
```

Comment: You have `groups` in your `lda` call, but `group` in your variable name.

Comment: Try replacing the question marks with `NA`.  As it stands, they are probably forcing the first column to be factors, which might not be what you want. In particular, the factor levels including `?` will be passed to 'lda', even though they don't appear in the first 60 rows.

Comment: Thank you. The group/groups was a typo. I replaced the question marks with NAs. When I re-run the code, there is no error, but still a 0.9 training prediction and 0.0 test prediction. I guess this means in this case, this algorithm is not suited to the binary classification of the last 10 rows of my data set that I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily, because you don't know what the test data should have been - as it stands, you are just comparing the predictions with question marks or NAs, hence the zero.  You need to test on some data for which you know the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have added in more code above, where I randomly select 50 of the first 60 rows (that are known groups), estimates the training parameters, and then classifies the remaining 10 samples. This is repeated 100 times. My predictive accuracy is still low (45%). I'm wondering, is it better to attempt a different modelling approach (e.g. glm) using the same data, or to somehow "edit" the data (e.g. feature selection somehow?) that is being used first and still use the same approach (although I have already removed two variables that were singular in the matrix).

Comment: It is probably worth trying some other methods, but it might just be that the data contains an inherently large random component, so you might never get much better - although with only two states it would be nice to at least get above 50%!

Comment: In your new code, are you excluding the ten entries at the end with the `NA`s? I was expecting to see `data <- data[1:60,]`. Otherwise your `data[-train,]` will include rows `61:70` as well.

Comment: I've changed that now thanks. I do have a question though. I had added in the same code, but I've changed the data set to iris. When I set n to 120 and nt to 90, merrlin is -0.887. When I set n to 150 and nt to 140, merrlin is 0.026. I can't get my head around what the -0.887 means, given that 0.026 is a 2.6% mis-classification rate (I think). So I'm wondering if I'm still doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up answer to the comments above...

In your example with `iris`, if you set `n` to 120, then you have to limit the data to the first `n` rows, otherwise `data[-train,]` will include rows `121:150` as well as the ones you are expecting.

I've made a few small changes below...

```
library(MASS)
n = 120
nt = 90
neval = n-nt
rep=100
errlin = dim(rep)
set.seed(123456789)
data <-iris[1:n,] # here is where you need to keep your data to n rows
for (k in 1:rep) {
  train = sample(1:n,nt)
  data.train <-data[train,]
  data.test <-data[-train,] #now excludes iris[(n+1):150,]
  m1 = lda(Species ~ .,data.train)
  tablin = table(data.test$Species,predict(m1,data.test)$class) #edited first term
  errlin[k] = (neval-sum(diag(tablin)))/neval
}

merrlin=mean(errlin)
merrlin

[1] 0.019
```

Which is a much better error rate!

Comment: Thank you. If I move to a completely different external server that hasn't been open until now (i.e. so a totally new terminal/server/copy of R), copy and paste the exact above text into an R script, and run the R script, I get merrlin = 0.019? Maybe this is just a small issue I can figure out, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry - so do I - I must have rerun the loop without redoing the `set.seed` line!  Corrected above.